# InLinks and OutLinks not displaying when level is changed in IBM Doors

Tags: ibm-doors

Hi Everyone hope all are good in this COVID time

So In a standard, all levels view i am able to view the links but when i change the view to level1 the links are not displayed.How can i display it any idea,why i need is i dont need to much data as in all level just enough as in level 1 view.
[image: All level, Standard]

[image: Level, Standard 1]

Thanks in advance

Comment: you removed your screenshot in order to not provide internal information about your work. While I understand this, my answer makes less sense now, and with the additional changes to your question, it is more difficult to understand both question and answer. You should at least re-insert the screenshot. Use a tool like "greenshot" to blur out sensitive data.

Comment: Sorry Mike thankyou for your answer really means a lot sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that the links are not shown: after all, Object 644 "ABCD" is not linked to any other object and changing the view to level 1 does exactly this: it shows only objects of Level 1 and nothing else, there is no cumulation.

The solution for your problem depends on what you want to do concretely.
If your goal is to count the links in the chapter, you could probably write a Layout DXL column like this

```
void recursiveCountOutLinks(Object o, int &iCount) {
    // first count the links going out of Object o
    Link l
    for l in o->"*" do iCount++
    // next, add all Links on lower levels
    Object oChild
    for oChild in o do {
        if isDeleted(oChild) then continue
        recursiveCountOutLinks (oChild, iCount)
    }
}

int iTotal = 0
if (level obj == 1) {
    recursiveCountOutLinks(obj, iTotal) 
    display iTotal ""
}
```

If your goal is to export these links you will have to adopt your exporter by doing this recursively as shown above.

Comment: How can i do it seperately for inlinks and outlinks im kinda trying to create a comparative graph in excel i mean separate LayoutDXL for in link and out link thanks in advance sorry again mike for that

Comment: create a function `recursiveCountInLinks` opposed to `recursiveCountOutLinks`. Change the variable `Link l` to `LinkRef lr`.  The loop will be `for lr in o<-"*"`